# posix_spawn and sharing filedescriptors

Tags: c, posix, swift

I'm toying around with a side project where I want to have multiple processes share the same listening socket. In the linux documentation I read that `posix_spawn` will retain the filedescriptors so it should work perfectly; but I'm unsure on how this sharing is actually done.

Passing the filedescriptor as an argument feels hacky in a way, so does hardcoding the value of the FD even though it'll likely by the same its just not correct.

Q: How does one correctly use file descriptor sharing in child processes?
All the results I find is how to prevent it, but in this case its desired behaviour :-)

Sample code I'm playing with:

```
let pathToExecutable = CommandLine.arguments[0]

// CLI Options parsing
let options = IgniteOptions.parseOrExit()

// For now the child does nothing.
if (options.isChild) {
    print("Hello World from child process!")
    exit(0)
}

// Creates and binds a TCP socket to the given host / port
let socket = Socket(host: "0.0.0.0", port: options.port)

// Calls posix_spawn in a swift friendly manner (only transforms the params really)
let pid = try spawn(pathToExecutable, args: [pathToExecutable, "-d"])
print("PID of child: \(pid)")
```

Comment: Pass the descriptor as an argument to the program.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, i'll be doing that then. I don't have that much unix-like programming experience so I might be more averse to doing that than I should be.